# How to use function pointer to access functions from multiple files

Tags: c, function-pointers

I do have the following structure. I need to check whether a particular file contains the specified function.If yes i need to execute it. I am new to C. How could we handle this

```
struct {
    char *filename;
    char *funcname;
    int (*funcptr)();
} symtab[] = {
    { "filename1", "one_func", one_func },
    { "filename2", "two_func", two_func },
};
```

I have the following code to check for functions using function pointer without considering the file:

```
int one_func(), two_func();
int (*findfunc(char *)) ();

struct {
        char *name;
        int (*funcptr) ();
} symtab[] = {
    { "one_func", one_func },
    { "two_func", two_func },
}; 

int (*findfunc(char *name)) () 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(symtab) / sizeof(symtab[0]); i++) 
        {
        if (strcmp(name, symtab[i].name) == 0)
        return symtab[i].funcptr;
        }
    puts("function not defined");
    return NULL;
}

int one_func()
{
    puts("one");
    return 0;
}

int two_func()
{
    puts("two");
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char *funcname = "two_func";
    int (*funcp) () = findfunc(funcname);
    if (funcp != NULL)
    (*funcp) ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: During runtime? Use shared libraries `.dll` on windows -> use `loadlibrary` and friends, `.so` on linux -> use `dlopen` and friends. Examples on wikipedia (for some reason) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_  trying to achieve?

Comment: BTW: please indent your code correctly.

Comment: i do have a char* variable pointing to a file, another char* variable pointing  to a function. In the main program i need to call a function after checking whether it exists in a set of files, symbol table can be maintained consisting of file information

Comment: There isn't a platform-independent API to find functions by name plus filename. If the function is externally visible, you can find it by name alone (but you won't be able to tell which file contains the name).  If the function is not externally visible, only debugger-style management of symbols from object files will allow you to access the function by name, and that sort of access is inherently platform-dependent if not platform-specific.  (The code might work on all platforms that use ELF format, but what works on ELF won't work with other object file formats.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using gcc compiler on CentOS

Comment: Fine. Have fun. Look up `libelf` and see what it provides. When you've written 30% of a debugger, you can probably get what you want done.  Until you've done that, you're unlikely to be successful. Or, 'in my opinion, …'. There might be some magic I don't know about that will do it for you, but I have serious doubts about it. Note that if any of the functions comes from a shared library, that will add to the complexity. Also, it isn't clear whether the file name you plan to use is a source file name, an object file name, a shared object name, or what. It doesn't matter to me; it will to you.

Comment: @martin sebastian. I've questions for you: Do you are searching for the functions you need to execute in elf files (compiled library or obj)? Do you are searching for a method to call functions that are inside your program in functions of a logical flow that depends or uses the filename you specified in the structure `symtab[]`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler File name i plan to use is source file name

Comment: @SergioFormiggini a method to call functions that are inside my program in functions of a logical flow that depends or uses the filenames you specified in the structure

Comment: Wonderful.  Soure file names are not guaranteed to be unique across the project — they don't have to be.  That is, different libraries can have source file `utils.c` containing different sets of functions.  It just adds to the complexity of what you're trying to do.  I strongly recommend rethinking what you're trying to do — that's the point of the [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) comment that was already made.  What is the goal that you are trying to achieve by this cockamamy system that you're trying to devise that is fighting against what the toolchain provides?

Comment: @Martin Sebastian. Ok! I understand. I'm writing a little code that selects functions in operation of a specified function name. I'll post it here when it's possible (I'm at work).

Comment: this seems like a severe X/Y problem; why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple code that can call the functions inside itself in operation of a "mnemonic" name. Once you compile this code an executable is generated. This executable requires two input parameters. Then you may run it in your terminal as:

prompt$ prgname fnName parm

where:

- prgname is the name you use to obtain the executable.
- fnName is the "mnemonic" name you insert into the structure (field `fnName` of the structure typedefined `tSymTab`) for the function.
- parm is a parameter (string) to be passed to the function to call by the "mnemonic" name.

Here the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 /*
  * parm may be used to send data to the function (void
  * because data may be of different kinds)
*/
typedef int tFn(void *parm);

typedef struct symTab {
    const char * fileName;
    const char * fnName;  //fnName shall be every name you want use to call the
                          //function pointed by fn
    tFn * fn;
} tSymTab;

tFn * findFunc(const char * fnName);
int func1(void *);
int func2(void *);

tSymTab symTab[]={
  {"f1.txt","func1",func1},
  {"f2.txt","func2",func2},

  // THIS MUST BE ALWAYS THE LAST LINE
  {"","",NULL}
};

int func1(void *parm)
{
    char * value = (char *)parm;

    printf("I'm in func1 --- the parm value is %s\n",value);

    return 0;
}

int func2(void *parm)
{
    char * value = (char *)parm;

    printf("I'm in func2 --- the parm value is %s\n",value);

    return 0;
}

tFn * findFunc(const char * fnName)
{
    int idx=0;

    while(symTab[idx].fn!=NULL && strcmp(symTab[idx].fnName,fnName))
        idx++;

    return symTab[idx].fn;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    tFn * fn;

    if (argc<3) {
        printf("%s needs two input parameters:\n\n\tThe function name\n\n\ta simple text\n\n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    fn=findFunc(argv[1]);
    if (fn!=NULL) {
        fn(argv[2]);
    } else {
        printf("The function name %s hasn't a corresponding function in this code!\n",argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thankyou for the support. I have a different scenaroi.My scenario is the func1 resides in f1.txt  and function2 inf2.txt.